# Return a loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, return

I have a function, which display posts from category:

```
function display_posts() {
  if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=4');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      $result =  '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
      return $result;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  endif;
}
```

But it returns only one article, instead four. But with this function everything works good:

```
function display_posts() {
  if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=4');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      echo  '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  endif;
}
```

So, how to return a loop from a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` exits the function immediately.  If you want to concatenate (join) all the results together, you'll need to return after the loop - something like this:

```
function display_posts() {
  $result = '';
  if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=4');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      $result .=  '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  endif;
  return $result;
}
```

Note the `.` before the `=`, which does the concatenation.

But I doubt you should be using `query_posts()` - `get_posts()` is probably a better choice.  Have a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) on the WordPress stackexchange.